# Azure devops - build number vs build id

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration

Documentation says:

*Build.BuildId* - The ID of the record for the completed build.

*Build.BuildNumber* - The name of the completed build, also known as the run number and that it can be customized.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services

If you create a fresh build pipeline and do not customize BuildNumber format:

> it will be given a unique integer as its name

In this case, is BuildNumber and BuildId exactly the same?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it's not necessary the same.
I just checked my classic and yml pipelines.

For `classic` build id and number are integers and are the same if not customized.

For `yml` build pipeline and build id is an integer and build number consists of current date and number of tries per day. As per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) the format is `$(Date:yyyyMMdd).$(Rev:r)`.

[image]

Comment: In YAML , the buildnumnber format is :` $(Date:yyyyMMdd).$(Rev:r)` This is a customize BuildNumber.  You need to read the **Question** :If you create a fresh build pipeline and do not customize BuildNumber format:
it will be given a unique integer as its name .In this case, is BuildNumber and BuildId exactly the same?  customer illustrates a situation.  Your answer does not apply to the customer's situation

Comment: Well if I didn't do anything to customize it in the yml file then it is not customized right? I didn't. It is by default like this. And it is not the same. OP didn't specify which build definition he has yml or classic one. And his link leads to yml arnchor in the article. @KevinLu-MSFT

Comment: Obviously the customer is a classic pipeline. Because this statement: it will be given a unique integer as its name https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic In this doc, this statement is in classic pipeline

Comment: On the other hand , 20210826.3 is not integer

Comment: Come on, read your link. `In YAML, this property is called name and is at the root level of a pipeline. If not specified, your run is given a unique integer as its name.` First of all this statement is false, second of all in the very first line on the page it is said `The default value for run number is $(Date:yyyyMMdd).$(Rev:r).` Which means that by default build number and id are not the same. But! I just checked my classic pipelines and indeed by default id and number are the same. So documentation might use some improvements there. @KevinLu-MSFT

Answer (score 5):

> In this case, is BuildNumber and BuildId exactly the same?

Yes. When you don't customize BuildNumber format, the value of the two variables are the same.

Here is an example：

No define Build number:

[image]

output the two variables:

```
- powershell: |
   echo $(build.buildid)
   
   echo $(build.buildnumber)
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
```

**Result:** The value is same.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, when you create a new build pipeline without customize the build number it will be the same as the build id + the commit message.

For example (4348 is the build id):

```
4348 test commit
```